Apply Fubini's theorem to $\int^1_0\int^2_{y^2}x^2y-y^2x$

Can Fubini's theorem be used for the integral $$\int^1_0\int^2_{y^2}(x^2y-y^2x)\text{d}x\text{d}y\ \ ?$$ Why? If yes, explicitly write the integral with the corresponding integral limits.

The integral above yields a result of $\frac{39}{56}$.
To answer the question I would say that we can apply Fubini's theorem, since $f$ (defined as the function in the integral) is continuous. Then to compute the new integral limits:
if initially we had $$0\le y\le1,\ \ y^2\le x\le2,$$
now $0\le x\le2$ and $-\sqrt{x}\le y\le\sqrt{x}$, but $$\int^2_0\int^{\sqrt{x}}_{-\sqrt{x}}(x^2y-y^2x)\text{d}y\text{d}x=-\frac{32\sqrt{2}}{21}.$$
So, my question is: is it wrong that it is possible to apply Fubini's theorem or did I compute something wrongly?

To use Fubini's, you need that your function is in $L^1$, and while continuity implies measurability, you want to say slightly more.  In particular, your region of integration is compact, and so your function is bounded on the region, which implies the integral of the absolute value is bounded too.  But if you had not been on a bounded region, then you would have needed some other argument, because there are continuous functions on $\mathbb R^2$ where Fubini's does not work.  Continuity is certainly a large part of why you could apply Fubini, but it isn't the entire picture.

The region of integration is not a rectangle:

Reversing the order of integration will give you the sum of two double integrals.
